# When doing sendkeys the element is not highlighted in my app of appium code?

Tags: android, automation, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to execute the below code unable to goto the specific element

> DesiredCapabilities c=new DesiredCapabilities();
>         c.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
>         c.setCapability("deviceName", "ZZ2222HMLF");
>         c.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
>         c.setCapability("platformversion", "7.0");
>         c.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk");
>         //c.setCapability("noReset", true);
>         //c.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");      c.setCapability("appPackage","com.sisapp.in.sisapp");
>         c.setCapability("appActivity","md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity");
>         URL U=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");      WebDriver
>   driver=new AndroidDriver(U,c);

Displaying as below error in my console

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An
>   unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Cannot start the 'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' application.
>   Visit
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
>   for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original
>   error: 'Command 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   ZZ2222HMLF shell am start -W -n
>   com.sisapp.in.sisapp/md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity
>   -S' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.sisapp.in.sisapp/md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity } from null (pid=26065, uid=2000) not exported from uid 11113 at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636) at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerNative.java:3280)
>   at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:630) at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:388) at
>   com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51) at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:294)'; Code:
>   '1' Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time:
>   '2017-12-01T19:05:14.666Z' System info: host: 'GSPSDELL30', ip:
>   '10.10.4.192', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info: driver.version:
>   AndroidDriver remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side
>   error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot
>   start the 'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' application. Visit
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
>   for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original
>   error: 'Command 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   ZZ2222HMLF shell am start -W -n
>   com.sisapp.in.sisapp/md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity
>   -S' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.sisapp.in.sisapp/md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity } from null (pid=26065, uid=2000) not exported from uid 11113 at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636) at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerNative.java:3280)
>   at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:630) at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:388) at
>   com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51) at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:294)'; Code:
>   '1' at getResponseForW3CError
>   (C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.10.0\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
>   at asyncHandler
>   (C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.10.0\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:37)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
>   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown
>   Source) at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source) at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1) at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>   at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:83) at
>   io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:93) at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:72)
>   at Mobileapp1.Apptesting.main(Apptesting.java:33)

Appium server log:

> [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.10.0 [Appium] Appium REST http interface
>   listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723 [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
>   [HTTP]
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk","appActivity":"md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.sisapp.in.sisapp","browserName":"","deviceName":"ZZ2222HMLF","platformName":"Android","platformversion":"7.0"},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk","appActivity":"md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.sisapp.in.sisapp","browserName":"","deviceName":"ZZ2222HMLF","platformName":"Android","platformversion":"7.0"},"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"","platformName":"android"}]}}
>   [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args:
>   [{"app":"D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk","appActivity":"md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.sisapp.in.sisapp","browserName":"","deviceName":"ZZ2222HMLF","platformName":"Android","platformversion":"7.0"},null,{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk","appActivity":"md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.sisapp.in.sisapp","browserName":"","deviceName":"ZZ2222HMLF","platformName":"Android","platformversion":"7.0"},"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"","platformName":"android"}]}]
>   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1552558812095
>   (15:50:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) [Appium] Could not parse W3C
>   capabilities: 'deviceName' can't be blank [Appium] Trying to fix W3C
>   capabilities by merging them with JSONWP caps [BaseDriver] The
>   capabilities
>   ["app","appActivity","appPackage","deviceName","platformversion"] are
>   not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix [Appium]
>   Creating new AndroidDriver (v4.8.0) session [Appium] Capabilities:
>   [Appium]   app: D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk [Appium]
>   appActivity: md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity [Appium]
>   appPackage: com.sisapp.in.sisapp [Appium]   deviceName: ZZ2222HMLF
>   [Appium]   platformversion: 7.0 [Appium]   browserName:  [Appium]
>   platformName: android [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities
>   {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app... and MJSONWP desired capabilities
>   {"app":"D:\Appium\edTheSI... were provided [BaseDriver] Creating
>   session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app...
>   [BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not
>   recognized by appium: platformversion. [BaseDriver] Session created
>   with session id: 1b0921bc-0535-4428-a57a-356bafe42833 [AndroidDriver]
>   Java version is: 1.8.0_151 [ADB] Checking whether adb is present [ADB]
>   The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android SDK
>   root directory path. ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with
>   SDK 23+. Checking along PATH for adb. [ADB] Using adb from
>   D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe [ADB]  [AndroidDriver] Retrieving device
>   list [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device [ADB] Getting
>   connected devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [AndroidDriver] Using
>   device: ZZ2222HMLF [ADB] Setting device id to ZZ2222HMLF [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell getprop
>   ro.build.version.sdk' [ADB] Current device property
>   'ro.build.version.sdk': 24 [ADB] Device API level: 24 [AndroidDriver]
>   Consider setting 'automationName' capability to 'uiautomator2' on
>   Android >= 6, since UIAutomator framework is not maintained anymore by
>   the OS vendor. [BaseDriver] Using local app
>   'D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk' [AndroidDriver] Checking whether
>   app is actually present [AndroidDriver] Starting Android session [ADB]
>   Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF
>   wait-for-device' [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   ZZ2222HMLF shell echo ping' [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to
>   device... [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings [ADB]
>   Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell
>   dumpsys package io.appium.settings' [ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is
>   installed [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings' [ADB]
>   Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell
>   dumpsys package io.appium.settings' [ADB] Checking whether aapt is
>   present [ADB] The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the
>   Android SDK root directory path. ANDROID_HOME is required for
>   compatibility with SDK 23+. Checking along PATH for aapt. [ADB] Using
>   aapt from D:\Appium\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe [ADB]  [ADB] The
>   version name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal
>   to the application version name ('2.11.0' >= '2.11.0') [ADB] There is
>   no need to install/upgrade
>   'C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.10.0\resources\app\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
>   [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell
>   ps' [AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no
>   need to reset its permissions. [ADB] Device API level: 24 [ADB]
>   Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell
>   appops set io.appium.settings android:mock_location allow' [Logcat]
>   Starting logcat capture [ADB] Getting device platform version [ADB]
>   Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell
>   getprop ro.build.version.release' [ADB] Current device property
>   'ro.build.version.release': 7.0 [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell wm size'
>   [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell
>   getprop ro.product.model' [ADB] Current device property
>   'ro.product.model': Moto C Plus [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell getprop
>   ro.product.manufacturer' [ADB] Current device property
>   'ro.product.manufacturer': motorola [ADB] Getting install status for
>   com.sisapp.in.sisapp [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell dumpsys package com.sisapp.in.sisapp' [ADB]
>   'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' is installed [ADB] Getting install status for
>   com.sisapp.in.sisapp [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell dumpsys package com.sisapp.in.sisapp' [ADB]
>   'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' is installed [ADB] Getting package info for
>   'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell dumpsys package com.sisapp.in.sisapp' [ADB]
>   The version code of the installed 'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' is greater
>   than the application version code (23 > 22) [ADB] There is no need to
>   install/upgrade 'D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk' [AndroidDriver]
>   Performing fast reset on 'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' [ADB] Getting install
>   status for com.sisapp.in.sisapp [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell dumpsys
>   package com.sisapp.in.sisapp' [ADB] 'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' is
>   installed [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   ZZ2222HMLF shell am force-stop com.sisapp.in.sisapp' [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell pm clear
>   com.sisapp.in.sisapp' [AndroidDriver] Performed fast reset on the
>   installed 'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' application (stop and clear) [ADB]
>   Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell rm
>   -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json' [AndroidDriver] Extracting strings from apk [AndroidDriver] D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk
>   [AndroidDriver] undefined [AndroidDriver]
>   C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\Temp\com.sisapp.in.sisapp [ADB]
>   Extracting strings from for language: default [ADB] Successfully
>   extracted 175 strings from 'D:\Appium\edTheSIS_11_02_2019.apk'
>   resources for '(default)' configuration [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF push
>   C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\Temp\com.sisapp.in.sisapp\strings.json
>   /data/local/tmp' [AndroidBootstrap] Watching for bootstrap disconnect
>   [ADB] Forwarding system: 4724 to device: 4724 [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF forward tcp:4724
>   tcp:4724' [UiAutomator] Starting UiAutomator [UiAutomator] Moving to
>   state 'starting' [UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar [UiAutomator]
>   Found jar name: 'AppiumBootstrap.jar' [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF push
>   C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.10.0\resources\app\node_modules\appium-android-driver\bootstrap\bin\AppiumBootstrap.jar
>   /data/local/tmp/' [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
>   [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell ps' [ADB] No
>   'uiautomator' process has been found [UiAutomator] Starting
>   UIAutomator [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args:
>   ["-P",5037,"-s","ZZ2222HMLF","shell","uiautomator","runtest","AppiumBootstrap.jar","-c","io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap","-e","pkg","com.sisapp.in.sisapp","-e","disableAndroidWatchers",false,"-e","acceptSslCerts",false]
>   [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'online' [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP
>   LOG] [debug] json loading complete. [AndroidBootstrap] Android
>   bootstrap socket is now connected [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell dumpsys
>   window' [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Registered crash
>   watchers. [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Client connected
>   [AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing [ADB] Device
>   API level: 24 [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   ZZ2222HMLF shell am start -W -n
>   com.sisapp.in.sisapp/md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity
>   -S' [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell am start -W -n
>   com.sisapp.in.sisapp/md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity
>   -S' [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell am force-stop
>   com.sisapp.in.sisapp' [ADB] Pressing the HOME button [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell input
>   keyevent 3' [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android:
>   {"cmd":"shutdown"} [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data
>   from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"} [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG]
>   [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP
>   LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting
>   down"} [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
>   [UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator [UiAutomator] Moving to state
>   'stopping' [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] close
>   [socket][::/:::4724] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed
>   client connection [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT]
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1 [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT]
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=. [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT]
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner [AndroidBootstrap]
>   [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS:
>   class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO
>   STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1 [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO
>   STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0 [UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut
>   down normally [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped' [ADB] Attempting
>   to kill all uiautomator processes [ADB] Getting all processes with
>   uiautomator [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   ZZ2222HMLF shell ps' [ADB] No 'uiautomator' process has been found
>   [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped' [Logcat] Stopping logcat
>   capture [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   ZZ2222HMLF shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock' [AndroidDriver] Not
>   cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
>   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1552558837127
>   (15:50:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) [W3C] Encountered internal
>   error running command: Error: Cannot start the 'com.sisapp.in.sisapp'
>   application. Visit
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
>   for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original
>   error: 'Command 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   ZZ2222HMLF shell am start -W -n
>   com.sisapp.in.sisapp/md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity
>   -S' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.sisapp.in.sisapp/md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity } from null (pid=27285, uid=2000) not exported from uid 11113 [W3C]
>     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683) [W3C]  at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636) [W3C]   at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerNative.java:3280)
>   [W3C]     at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:630) [W3C]   at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:388) [W3C]   at
>   com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51) [W3C]    at
>   com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121) [W3C]    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>   [W3C]     at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:294)'; Code:
>   '1' [W3C]     at ADB.apkUtilsMethods.startApp
>   (C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.10.0\resources\app\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-utils.js:144:11)
>   [W3C]     at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session
>   500 25191 ms - 3184 [HTTP]

Answer (score 0):

When you install an App using Appium on the device you also need to start the activity also.

Just add the below capabilities in your code :

```
c.setCapability("appPackage", "<PACKAGE_NAME>");
c.setCapability("appActivity", "LOGINSCREEN_ACTIVITY_NAME");
```

Below is the sample capabilities to launch Amazon App:

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
 capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "<DEVICE_ID>");
 capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "<ANDROID_VERSION>");
 capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
 capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
 capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
 capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");
```

Comment: Displaying an error at below line:capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: You have to replace this with your APK file location.

Comment: added still getting the error as Cannot start the 'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' application.Command 'D\:\\Appium\\Sdk\\tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZZ2222HMLF shell am start -W -n com.sisapp.in.sisapp/md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity -S' exited with code 1

Comment: Can you post the Appium console log.

Comment: I have updated the console error message please check

Comment: I was talking about the Appium console log (It's present in the Appium desktop app), not the Eclipse. Can you also update the code you have written.

Comment: Are you sure the activity name (**md5b1afd03e09ce5243fd0287b176ff38ea.MainActivity**) is correct? Technically it should start with a package name.  Can you verify it in your AndroidManifest.xml .

Comment: Where can i find AndroidManifest.xml can u please say me

Comment: To access AndroidManifest.xml you should have access to its precompiled code. It's present in your root directory of App.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<manifest package="com.example.myapplication" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


-<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:supportsRtl="true" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true">


-<activity android:name=".MainActivity">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

Comment: **.MainActivity** This is your appActivity name. Kindly use this and check the output.

Comment: Cannot start the 'com.sisapp.in.sisapp' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name '.MainActivity' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity getting this error

Answer (score 0):

To Know the App Package and App Activity i have installed the apk info app and found the activities in the activities and now able to open the app.

Answer (score 0):

1. I used below mentioned DesiredCapabilities, to launch the application on the Emulator setup
2. You can call getAppiumDriver() function to start the driver setup and app launch on the said emulator.
3. The best way is to install Appium Desktop and try out the desired capabilities from the Inspector console on Appium Desktop.

   ```
   protected static AppiumDriver appDriver;

   protected AppiumDriver getAppiumDriver() throws MalformedURLException {

       if(appDriver == null)
       {                
           DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

           File appDir = new File("FOLDER LOCATION OF .APK");


           /* ANDROID DEPENDENCIES START*/

           File newApp = new File (appDir ,"APPLICATIONNAME.APK" );
           cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
           cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus5XAPI26");
           cap.setCapability("udid", "HT4AXJT03545");
           cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
           cap.setCapability("platformVersion","7.1.1");
           cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");

           /* ANDROID DEPENDENCIES END */


           cap.setCapability("app", newApp.getAbsolutePath());
           appDriver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
       }
    return appDriver;
   }
   ```